# How to add model value to the html attribute value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this code

```
@if (ViewBag.TechnologyNames != null)
          {
              foreach (var technologyName in ViewBag.TechnologyNames)
              {
                  if (@technologyName.TechnologyID == -1)
                  {
            <div class="CheckBoxItem">
                <input type="checkbox" name="option1" id="allTechnology" value="@technologyName.TechnologyID" checked="checked" />
                @technologyName.Name
            </div>
                }
                else
                {
                 <input type="checkbox" name="option2" id="tech"  value="@technologyName.TechnologyID" />
                @technologyName.Name
                }
              }
          }
```

What I need is somehow to add `@technologyName.TechnologyID` to `id="tech"` to have at the end

```
id="tech_123"
```

How I can do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

try this (basically adding parenthesis around the property):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="option2" id="tech_
@(technologyName.TechnologyID)"  value="@technologyName.TechnologyID" />
```

Comment: my pleasure - it's a well 'hidden' feature :)

Comment: I just put some ++++ for some of your answers too. Be blessed man! )))

Comment: @jimtollan - what is the syntax for `aspx engine` view?